# Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: html, apache, google-chrome, html5-video, mime-types

Hello friends when i added Captions track tag in video tag then in chrome browser's console have coming this warning
 `Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost/video/media/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt".`
But my html page and Captions are working fine
[image: Warning]
i am using the xampp with apache web server for Localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my Research am providing this Solution, Because i am using apache web server so first of all i am created `.htaccess` file in the root directory of where `.vtt` type file are stored.

for example: `H:\xampp\htdocs\video\media\.htaccess`

Then am inserted  `AddType text/vtt .vtt` this content in `.htaccess` file.

am cleared cache from Chrome browser and Refreshed tab then `.vtt` MimeType Warning have gone.

> If you want for other web server you can follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268843/11554604)